# TikZ (tikzexternalize) + subcaptionbox error

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors, subcaption, tikz-external

### Update

The error comes up only if I change the pictures themselves or insert/delete a picture that occurs before them in the document. As a dirty workaround, I defined a command `\newcommand{\subcaptionfix}[1]{#1}` which I wrap around the subcaptionbox commands (including the first argument). If I need to change anything, I simply remove the `#1` so that LaTeX ignores the command. Afterwards, I can put it back.

A proper solution of the problem would be nicer but I am still having difficulties reproducing the error in a somewhat *minimal* example. Maybe I'll do it in a few weeks when I have more time.

---

I use `subcaption`'s  command `\subcaptionbox` twice in a figure. In each `subcaptionbox`, I place a `TikZ` picture. This works fine as long as I don't change one of the pictures. As soon as I change it, I get the following error:

```
! Package tikz Error: Sorry, the system call 'pdflatex -shell-escape -halt-on-e
rror -interaction=batchmode -jobname "msc-preliminary-figure0" "\def\tikzextern
alrealjob{msc-preliminary}\input{msc-preliminary}"' did NOT result in a usable 
output file 'msc-preliminary-figure0' (expected one of .pdf:.jpg:.jpeg:.png:). 
Please verify that you have enabled system calls. For pdflatex, this is 'pdflat
ex -shell-escape'. Sometimes it is also named 'write 18' or something like that
. Or maybe the command simply failed? Error messages can be found in 'msc-preli
minary-figure0.log'. If you continue now, I'll try to typeset the picture.

See the tikz package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.59 \end{tikzpicture}}

This error message was generated by an \errmessage
command, so I can't give any explicit help.
Pretend that you're Hercule Poirot: Examine all clues,
and deduce the truth by order and method.

LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `FMX/futm/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 6.99199pt on input line 1.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `U/futm/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 6.99199pt on input line 1.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `T1/futs/bx/n' in size <10> not available
(Font)              Font shape `T1/futs/b/n' tried instead on input line 59.
===== Image 'msc-preliminary-figure1' is up-to-date. ======
) [5]pdfTeX warning (ext4): destination with the same identifier (name{equation
.2.1}) has been already used, duplicate ignored
<to be read again> 
                   \relax 
l.45    \end{align}
                  [6pdfTeX warning (ext4): destination with the same identifier
 (name{equation.2.2}) has been already used, duplicate ignored

\AtBegShi@Output ...ipout \box \AtBeginShipoutBox 
                                                  \fi \fi 
l.59 \end{align}
                 <./msc-preliminary-figure1.pdf>]
```

using `subcaption`'s `subfigure` environment does not cause a similar problem, but the images are not aligned horizontally due to different caption lengths. Also, if I delete the `\subcaptionbox` command, make the changes and and insert them again, it works nicely.

I've tried to produce a minimal example, but the problem is that I couldn't reproduce the error. If this is relevant: I use `\usepgfplotslibrary{external}` and `\tikzexternalize`. My file structure looks like this:

Main document

```
\input{preamble.tex}
%... title and so on
\input{chapter1.tex}
\input{chapter2.tex}
%...
\input{chapterN.tex}
\input{appendix.tex}
```

Chapter 2: chapter2.tex

```
%...text
\begin{figure}
  \input{figurefile.tikz}
  \caption[short]{long}
  \label{fig:foobar}
\end{figure}
%...text
```

Figure: figurefile.tikz

```
\subcaptionbox{first subcaption\label{fig:foo}}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
  %...picture
\end{tikzpicture}}
\hfill
\subcaptionbox{second subcaption\label{fig:bar}}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
  %...picture
\end{tikzpicture}}
```

Has anything like this happened to anyone before?

Comment: Where you find file type `.tikz`? I newer hear about it. I suppose, that you have `.tex` file, which contain picture drawn with package `tikz`.

Comment: I could also name it `.tex` but I named it `.tikz` - that doesn't matter (by the way, the extension `.tikz` is even supported by TexStudio)

Comment: Please give us a complete minimal example which we can compile to reproduce the error. Code fragments are not very useful. I might or might not complete them in the way required to reproduce that error. I might produce a different error, missing essential bits. Or I might produce no error. And all that is a waste of effort since it is much easier for *you*, whose error it is, to construct a suitable example.

Comment: It is always possible (almost always possible) to produce an MWE. It is just a mechanical process. Remove code. Compile. Replace if error disappears. Remove other code. Compile. And so on. Rinse and repeat and you're done. Also, you haven't given us any information from the log file mentioned in the error, which only you have access to.

Comment: Okay I'll try it again tomorrow, but since I didn't succeed yet I thought maybe someone has had the same error before. I don't expect anyone to reproduce the problem from the short snippets, of course

Comment: It's stupid, without the babel package it seemed to work. With the package, the behavior was sometimes as described above, and sometimes, there was no error but the picture simply didn't change. Couldn't get any MWE that always behaves the same. Note, that in all cases it didn't work when I deleted all automatically created files (i.e. all non-tex, -bib and -TikZ files). I think, I'll stick to my workaround for the pictures in question...

Comment: And your question doesn't even mention `babel` or say whether you are using the TikZ `babel` library....